# My tooltip doesn't appear with styling and position

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm using bootstrap on my website and I want a tooltip to appear when hovered over a  `element.
Here's what I've done:`

```
 <code id="copystuff" onclick="CopyToClipboard('copystuff')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="Click to copy">Text</code>
```

Initialized js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' }); 
});
```

When I hover over the code element, the data of tooltip is displayed but somewhere else and without styling:[image]

The "click to copy" on the extreme left is the tooltip data and should appear above the given link to share

NB: FOr those who think that onclick="CopyToClipboard('copystuff')" is causing problems, removing it didnt help.

Please  help me fix this

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help you if you share some working example with us instead of images.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dsz2jskg/

Comment: use css position relative to that tool-tip div.... can u send me demo link?

Comment: even the simple code in w3schools didnt work https://jsfiddle.net/dsz2jskg/1/

Comment: Could not reproduce error on fillddle. For my project, the js is working fine dont know why bootstrap css for toolkit doesnt work